# Find the Speed of Touches and Swipes?

Tags: iphone, uitouch

I wanted to know how we can find the speed of user's Touch and Swipes. Can some one give a sample for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` has a `velocityInView:` method (measured in points per second).

Comment: Hi Ole,

When I used it, I got a CGPoint Value.How can I find the Speed with that?

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the documentation? It's all explained there.

Comment: Hi OLe Begemann,

I checked there and it seems that x represents Horizontal velocity per second and y represents the Vertical velocity per second. Do you have any idea by which we can get the concrete speed using these values?

Comment: The Pythagorean Theorem should help you there: a² + b² = c².